# Как будет корректнее?

Tags: стилистика

Как лучше написать фразу: "последовавший перерыв в следовании цивилизованным правилам"?

**Обновление**

Полный вариант предложения:

> Последовавший более чем 50-летний перерыв в следовании цивилизованным правилам формирования законодательства вновь актуализирует необходимость к исследованию зарубежного опыта законодательного регулирования.

Comment: Похоже на перевод с иностранного языка. Как-то совсем не по-русски. Нужен контекст, желательно на языке оригинала. Переводить ведь нужно смысл, а не грамматические формы.

Comment: roman, дайте нормальный английский (или какой он там) текст. После машинных переводчиков переводить много сложнее.

Comment: "После 50 лет, в течение которых отнюдь не следовали цивилизованным правилам при формировании законодательства, стала снова актуальной необходимость исследовать зарубежный опыт регулирования законотворчества". Любите глаголы, они хорошие.

Comment: В соответствии с ниже стоящим комментарием @behemothus, прошу Вас перенести всё предложение из комментария в Ваш вопрос — ибо, по моему мнению, править надо предложение целиком.

Answer (score -1):

Ну если нужно конкретно это предложение, и, если предположить, что это английский, то можно сделать так.
"Следуя цивилизованным правилам, последовал перерыв."
Хотя, лично мне "цивилизованные правила" как-то не очень нравятся! Как-то корявенько...
Как было сказано, в идеале, нужен контекст!

Comment: Вот именно так - не надо. И дело не в правилах, а в том, что 
"Подъезжая к станции, с меня слетела шляпа".